# trying to add hierarchy constraints to delegate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a delegate statement that works like so:

```
$("body").delegate("tr[type='option']",'mouseenter',function(){
```

The problem is that it's grabbing  elements from tables I don't want. So I tried:

```
$("body").delegate("table[class='ms-MenuUI'] > tr[type='option']",'mouseenter',function(){
```

Which isn't working at all (though I'm not getting any console errors). Just wondering how I can tighten this up so it's only grabbing table rows from the specific table I want.

NOTE: the table does not exist in the DOM on page load, and is dynamically created/destroyed after the doc is ready, thus the need for delegate to begin with.

EDIT:
As per my comment below, I'm using [] because the attribute of the parent is variable, and it's my understanding that they should work interchangeably with the attribute short-hand (i.e. '.'). A sample of the dynamic code would be:

```
$('body').delegate('table[' + parentAttribType + "='" + parentAttribValue + "'] > tr[" + rowAttrbType + "='" + rowAttribValue + "']"), 'mouseenter', function(){
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, the event handler gets bound to the table using 'tr td' as its event target.

```
$('table[class=ms-MenuUI]').delegate('tr td', 'mouseenter', function() {

});
```

FYI -

If you are going to use `$('body').delegate('', )` then its probably better to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which binds event handlers to the document level anyways.

EDIT: Sorry didn't read your entire post, delegate the event to an element that either contains the table, or use .live().

Comment: @John It's never better to use `live`.  (1) It has horrid syntax, (2) it requires an extra selector when doing the delegation.

Comment: this looks like it's the right solution. I disagree that delegate is *always* better than live - it's a matter of design constraints and solution needs imo...

Comment: Thanks John, I'm going to move forward with live()

Comment: @John How? They are functionally equivalent, except for  live's odd syntax and a slight performance increase for `$(document)` over `$('tr td')`.

Comment: If you decide to bind a handler to the document level what would you prefer?  $(document).delegate('tr td', 'click', fn); or $('tr td').live('click', fn);  You are right they same thing.  For simplicity, live may be the choice for certain people.  Delegate() was created after live() purely to fix the ugly syntax of using $('tr td', $('table')[0]).live('click', fn).  I suggested .live() in the above answer because he was binding a handler to the <body> when he could just use .live() if he was going to be doing that.  Questions? Concerns?

Comment: I chose John's answer because of the comment he just made. I don't want to bind to the document and I tend to stand apart from the general census on syntax 'prettiness' of live() - I like it just find. I won't start a rant about syntax here; bottom line is that this answer is what got me to my solution the fastest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the class selector `.` for classes, not the attribute selector `[]`:

```
$("body").delegate("table.ms-MenuUI > tr[type='option']",'mouseenter',function(){
```

Also, your browser may be introducing a `tbody` element.  If you can, remove the `>`.

Comment: Is that mandatory? My sample is hard-coded, but the attribute being selected is dynamic and won't always be class. Using [] allows me to pass the attribute type as a variable easily in the selector, and afaik the functionality should be the same. I'll update with another example.

Comment: Yes, it should work, it's just ugly syntax.  I fancy the `tbody` issue may be the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
$("table[class=ms-MenuUI] tr td").live('mouseenter',function(){
  /* yout code*/
});
```

The live is like bind but works on dhtml.